# Percona server Master-Slave version query

Tags: replication, percona, percona-server

I have a master with percona server (5.6.25) running in RHEL host and a slave of the same version. I'm facing some corruption issues in replication slave and I'm thinking of rebuilding the slave from scratch.

Just a query, can I have the slave of version 5.6.31 instead of the original master version? What could be the issues that could occur?

Answer (score 0):

yes, it will work. generally it is recommended that slaves be the same or of higher version than its master.

Comment: ok what if I change this config to active master-passive master config. Even then will it work?

Comment: in theory it should still work because you're using the same major version. but to be sure check release notes from 5.6.25+ to 5.6.31 for incompatible changes if there are any.